# Php скрипт не выполняется, если сайт лежит

Tags: php, curl

Добрый день, у меня есть скрипт на php, который состоит из 3 частей - парсит разные сайты. Но такая проблема - если первый из сайтов лежит - то остальные не парсятся почемуто. Выдается ошибка

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in Z:\home\localhost\www\script.php on line 34

и все. Подскажите пожалуйста как этого избежать

Comment: niki-timofe, почитал, но к сожалению ничего не понял, т.к. полный 0 в php

Заметил, что если через консоль выполнять скрипт, то он нормально дальше идет, по другим сайтам, если первый лежит. А через веб-интерфейс такая вот ошибка (

Comment: @Парень, Если Вы не знаете основ [**`ООП`**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%E1%FA%E5%EA%F2%ED%EE-%EE%F0%E8%E5%ED%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%ED%EE%E5_%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5), то помочь Вам нечем...

Comment: @niki-timofe, ООП то здесь причем? Хабра перечитали что-ли?

Answer (score 4):

Судя по метке CURL, используется именно он.
Вот и настраивать нужно [опции CURL](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.curl-setopt.html), чтобы не ждал ответа бесконечно - до таймаута.
То есть это CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT и CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.

Возможно, я не права и слово curl в метках случайно ? ) Тогда приводите код. Поможем, даже если Вы ООП не знаете.

Answer (score 3):

Либо в `php.ini`:

```
 max_execution_time = 120
```

Либо в `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_php>
    php_value max_execution_time 120
</IfModule>
```

Если PHP работает не в безопасном режиме, то прям в коде:

```
set_time_limit(120);
```

Comment: Мне одному кажется, что достаточно задать таймаут сокету, который читает лежачий сайт?)

Comment: @KiTE, а разве ошибка просто не ***`отсрочится`*** на 90 секунд??

Comment: У тебя скрипт останавливается по таймауту. Именно в этом проблема. Один из вариантов решения - рассчитать максимальное время необходимое для обработки заданного кол-ва страниц, и выставить его в `max_execution_time`.

Comment: @Sh4dow, да, у CURL-сессии есть параметр `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`, и его нужно  использовать. Но, как я понял, топикстартер последовательно обрабатывает несколько страниц за один проход, и рано или поздно он упрется в `max_execution_time`.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про [**`обработку исключений`**](http://www.php.su/learnphp/phpoo/?php5_3).

Answer (score 0):

А может проще перед тем как парсить сайт проверять на то лежит он или нет через header? и если тупо лежит то исключать его и не пробовать даже загрузить...